# how to bind command-delete (command-backspace) to 'kill-whole-line' in bash terminal?

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal

I'm on mac and I'm trying to unify my keyboard shortcuts across applications.

In so doing, I'd like to make <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> behave like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd> currently behaves in the terminal. I was hoping I could use ~/.inputrc to create this binding. For example by putting

```
"\C-t": kill-whole-line
```

in .inputrc and running `bind -f ~/.inputrc` I could get control-t to kill the contents of the terminal line (backwards and forwards, close enough to control-U for my purposes), but I don't know the appropriate key codes for command-backspace, or if such codes exist!

(Nb: For me <kbd>Backspace</kbd> is the key with <kbd>Delete</kbd> printed on it on the Mac keyboard---the key that erases stuff before the cursor.)